# Как выбрать уникальные строки с максимальным значением столбца для каждого элемента

Tags: mysql, sql

Версия mysql 5.5.50

Объясню, полностью задачу.

Есть таблица из элементов, в которую будет ежедневно добавляться n-ное количество записей, а так же, если на клиенте происходит обновление какой то строки, то на сервере у соответствующей создаётся новая ревизия.

После любой манипуляции с таблицей на клиентской стороне расширяется выпадающий список из элементов, которые соответствуют актуальному состоянию таблицы на клиентской стороне
А у себя он всегда видит только записи со статусом 1 и максимальной ревизий для конкретного mp_id. Объясню по шагам, для лучшего понимания вопроса.

---

Вначале данные занесли в эту таблицу программно (импортом из любой другой базы)

#### Первая итерация

в таком виде данные хранятся в базе:

```
+----+-------+---------+----------+--------+
| id | mp_id | name    | revision | status |
+----+-------+---------+----------+--------+
|  1 |     1 | apples  |        1 |      1 |
|  2 |     2 | bananas |        1 |      1 |
|  3 |     3 | oranges |        1 |      1 |
|  4 |     4 | lemons  |        1 |      1 |
+----+-------+---------+----------+--------+
```

на этом этапе пользователю возвращаются такие же данные и он видит такую же таблицу, что и в базе:

*это данные, которые должны ему вернуться в интерфейс:*

```
+----+-------+---------+----------+--------+
| id | mp_id | name    | revision | status |
+----+-------+---------+----------+--------+
|  1 |     1 | apples  |        1 |      1 |
|  2 |     2 | bananas |        1 |      1 |
|  3 |     3 | oranges |        1 |      1 |
|  4 |     4 | lemons  |        1 |      1 |
+----+-------+---------+----------+--------+
```

над которой есть выпадающий список пока еще из одного элемента (ведь это первая итерация).

---

При добавлении новой записи в интерфейсе на клиентской стороне, на сервере в базу так же добавится строка.

#### Вторая итерация

теперь таблица в базе выглядит так:

```
+----+-------+------------+----------+--------+
| id | mp_id | name       | revision | status |
+----+-------+------------+----------+--------+
|  1 |     1 | apples     |        1 |      1 |
|  2 |     2 | bananas    |        1 |      1 |
|  3 |     3 | oranges    |        1 |      1 |
|  4 |     4 | lemons     |        1 |      1 |
|  5 |     9 | watermelon |        1 |      1 |
+----+-------+------------+----------+--------+
```

на этом этапе пользователь в интерфейсе так же видит таблицу как  базе:

```
+----+-------+------------+----------+--------+
| id | mp_id | name       | revision | status |
+----+-------+------------+----------+--------+
|  1 |     1 | apples     |        1 |      1 |
|  2 |     2 | bananas    |        1 |      1 |
|  3 |     3 | oranges    |        1 |      1 |
|  4 |     4 | lemons     |        1 |      1 |
|  5 |     9 | watermelon |        1 |      1 |
+----+-------+------------+----------+--------+
```

но выпадающий список над ней уже содержит два элемента. При выборе первого, пользователь увидит таблицу как на первой итерации, а при выборе второго вернется к текущей

---

После того как в интерфейсе отредактировали одну из строк например `bananas`, в таблицу на сервере добавилась строка

#### Третья итерация

таблица в базе выглядит так:

```
+----+-------+------------+----------+--------+
| id | mp_id | name       | revision | status |
+----+-------+------------+----------+--------+
|  1 |     1 | apples     |        1 |      1 |
|  2 |     2 | bananas    |        1 |      1 |
|  3 |     3 | oranges    |        1 |      1 |
|  4 |     4 | lemons     |        1 |      1 |
|  5 |     9 | watermelon |        1 |      1 |
|  6 |     2 | bananas    |        2 |      1 |
+----+-------+------------+----------+--------+
```

но в интерфейсе пользователь должен увидеть таблицу в таком виде:

```
+----+-------+------------+----------+--------+
| id | mp_id | name       | revision | status |
+----+-------+------------+----------+--------+
|  1 |     1 | apples     |        1 |      1 |
|  3 |     3 | oranges    |        1 |      1 |
|  4 |     4 | lemons     |        1 |      1 |
|  5 |     9 | watermelon |        1 |      1 |
|  6 |     2 | bananas    |        2 |      1 |
+----+-------+------------+----------+--------+
```

выпадающий список будет содержать 3 элемента

---

после того как на клиенте удалили одну из строк например `apples`

#### Четвертая итерация

таблица в базе будет выглядеть так:

```
+----+-------+------------+----------+--------+
| id | mp_id | name       | revision | status |
+----+-------+------------+----------+--------+
|  1 |     1 | apples     |        1 |      1 |
|  2 |     2 | bananas    |        1 |      1 |
|  3 |     3 | oranges    |        1 |      1 |
|  4 |     4 | lemons     |        1 |      1 |
|  5 |     9 | watermelon |        1 |      1 |
|  6 |     2 | bananas    |        2 |      1 |
|  7 |     1 | apples     |        2 |      0 |
+----+-------+------------+----------+--------+
```

в интерфейсе пользователь увидит таблицу уже вот так:

```
+----+-------+------------+----------+--------+
| id | mp_id | name       | revision | status |
+----+-------+------------+----------+--------+
|  3 |     3 | oranges    |        1 |      1 |
|  4 |     4 | lemons     |        1 |      1 |
|  5 |     9 | watermelon |        1 |      1 |
|  6 |     2 | bananas    |        2 |      1 |
+----+-------+------------+----------+--------+
```

а выпадающий список будет содержать 4 элемента, для возможности переключиться к любому из состояний.

---

После удаления еще одной строки `bananas` из таблицы

#### Пятая итерация

в базе таблица будет выглядеть вот так:

```
+----+-------+------------+----------+--------+
| id | mp_id | name       | revision | status |
+----+-------+------------+----------+--------+
|  1 |     1 | apples     |        1 |      1 |
|  2 |     2 | bananas    |        1 |      1 |
|  3 |     3 | oranges    |        1 |      1 |
|  4 |     4 | lemons     |        1 |      1 |
|  5 |     9 | watermelon |        1 |      1 |
|  6 |     2 | bananas    |        2 |      1 |
|  7 |     1 | apples     |        2 |      0 |
|  8 |     2 | bananas    |        3 |      0 |
+----+-------+------------+----------+--------+
```

пользователю же в интерфейс должны вернуться вот эти данные:

```
+----+-------+------------+----------+--------+
| id | mp_id | name       | revision | status |
+----+-------+------------+----------+--------+
|  3 |     3 | oranges    |        1 |      1 |
|  4 |     4 | lemons     |        1 |      1 |
|  5 |     9 | watermelon |        1 |      1 |
+----+-------+------------+----------+--------+
```

теперь выпадающий список над нашей таблицей должен содержать 5 элементов

---

Итак после удаления `bananas` на клиентской стороне выпадающий список состоит уже из 5 строк.
Пользователь может выбирать любую из строк для того чтобы посмотреть, как выглядел его список на клиентской стороне.

**Обращу внимание, что пользователь не сможет отредактировать удаленную запись, вернувшись к тому состоянию, когда она еще была опубликована**

так как после редактирования создастся еще одна ревизия этой записи, просто у нее будет статус 0, а вся таблица перейдет на новую итерацию, то есть в нашем случае шестую.

При добавлении новой записи, или обновлении, мне нужно знать ревизию всех остальных записей, чтобы добавить их во вторую таблицу (состояний). Как мне кажется именно в новой таблице надо хранить актуальные id элементов для соответствующей итерации. Чтобы отдавать соответствующие этим id элементы, при выборе пользователем определенного состояния.

То есть вторая таблица мне нужна для того чтобы можно было быстро переключаться между состояниями первой.

при добавлении новой записи в таблицу (а она у нас добавляется всегда, если пользователь добавляет, редактирует или как ему кажется удаляет строку на клиентской стороне) попробовал выполнить вот такой запрос

```
SELECT DISTINCT mp_id, name, id FROM test WHERE status=1 ORDER BY revision DESC
```

но `DISTINCT` тут вообще никак не помог

**В итоге весь мой вопрос сводится к тому, чтобы на каждой итерации как-то получать последние ревизии всех фруктов (mp_id) из таблицы при условии, что их статус на текущий момент не равен 0. Вопрос как это сделать?** (главное получить, а записать их во вспомогательную таблицу, а затем сформировать из этого выпадающий список я смогу)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108349/discussion-on-question-by--------).

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо записывать в revision порядковый номер итерации и тогда ваша задача решаема, то есть ревизия хранит в себе порядковый номер итерации в которой это значение было записано, хотя данную роль лучше было бы возложить на индекс id, этому мешает то что вы за первую итерацию записали несколько значений. в конечном виде таблица будет выглядеть следующим образом

```
+----+-------+------------+----------+--------+
| id | mp_id | name       | revision | status |
+----+-------+------------+----------+--------+
|  1 |     1 | apples     |        1 |      1 |
|  2 |     2 | bananas    |        1 |      1 |
|  3 |     3 | oranges    |        1 |      1 |
|  4 |     4 | lemons     |        1 |      1 |
|  5 |     9 | watermelon |        2 |      1 |
|  6 |     2 | bananas    |        3 |      1 |
|  7 |     1 | apples     |        4 |      0 |
|  8 |     2 | bananas    |        5 |      0 |
+----+-------+------------+----------+--------+
```

Тогда можно вытащить любое предыдущее состояние запросом вида

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE status = 1 AND (mp_id, revision) in
   (SELECT mp_id, max(revision) FROM test WHERE revision<=3 GROUP BY mp_id)
```

или

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE status = 1 AND (mp_id, id) in 
   (SELECT mp_id, max(id) FROM test WHERE revision<=5 GROUP BY mp_id)
```

Сперва с помощью подзапроса мы выбираем для каждого mp_id строку с мах revision не зависимо от статуса 0 или 1, а уже после из этих значений ищем те что имеют статус=1. Изменяя revision<=1, 2, 3, 4 или 5 и т.д. можно вывести состояние после любой итерации.

В вашем варианте проблема заключается в том что например после второй итерации совсем не понятно что их было 2, а после четвёртой итерации глядя на таблицу не понятно сколько 2, 3 или 4?

Comment: А я вот и думаю, что может быть, на каждой итерации извлекать id всех строк с актуальной ревизией и помещать их во вспомогательную таблицу? То есть в новой таблице под номером каждой итерации будут храниться id тех строк, которые были актуальны на момент соответствующей итерации. Вопрос заключается только в том как выбирать актуальные id, чтобы записать во вспомогательную таблицу) но кажется ваши запросы помогут мне справиться с этой задачей

Comment: вот такой запрос `SELECT * FROM test WHERE status = 1 AND (mp_id, revision) in (SELECT mp_id, max(revision) FROM test GROUP BY mp_id)` полностью решает мою задачу. При добавлении новой записи выполняется этот запрос, который извлекает актуальные записи из таблицы а затем вторым запросом я уже их буду помещать во вторую таблицу

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, длинно, поэтому не комментарием, а как ответ.

---

Прочитал обновлённые пояснения. Понял, что задача нерешаема из-за противоречий. Объясняю.

Исходное состояние мы видим. Теперь представь, что вопрос выглядит так (исходное состояние - совпадает с состоянием в исходном вопросе, что наблюдается на шаге 2):

---

> ### В таком виде изначально занесли данные в таблицу (первая итерация)
>
> ```
> +----+-------+------------+----------+--------+
> | id | mp_id | name       | revision | status |
> +----+-------+------------+----------+--------+
> |  1 |     1 | apples     |        1 |      1 |
> |  2 |     2 | bananas    |        1 |      1 |
> |  3 |     3 | oranges    |        1 |      1 |
> |  4 |     4 | lemons     |        1 |      1 |
> |  5 |     9 | watermelon |        1 |      1 |
> +----+-------+------------+----------+--------+
> ```
>
> на этом этапе в выпадающем списке один элемент, при выборе которого клиенту
>   возвращается
>
> ```
> +----+-------+------------+----------+--------+
> | id | mp_id | name       | revision | status |
> +----+-------+------------+----------+--------+
> |  1 |     1 | apples     |        1 |      1 |
> |  2 |     2 | bananas    |        1 |      1 |
> |  3 |     3 | oranges    |        1 |      1 |
> |  4 |     4 | lemons     |        1 |      1 |
> |  5 |     9 | watermelon |        1 |      1 |
> +----+-------+------------+----------+--------+
> ```

---

А теперь: "Внимание - вопрос!".

Таблица данных выглядит как

```
+----+-------+------------+----------+--------+
| id | mp_id | name       | revision | status |
+----+-------+------------+----------+--------+
|  1 |     1 | apples     |        1 |      1 |
|  2 |     2 | bananas    |        1 |      1 |
|  3 |     3 | oranges    |        1 |      1 |
|  4 |     4 | lemons     |        1 |      1 |
|  5 |     9 | watermelon |        1 |      1 |
+----+-------+------------+----------+--------+
```

Сколько следует показать элементов - один (как здесь) или два (как в исходном вопросе)?

Ответ дать на основании данных **ТОЛЬКО** из таблицы - ибо по условиям задачи иных исходных данных у нас **НЕТ**.

Comment: Не совсем понял, вопрос. На первой итерации моя таблица состоит из 4 элементов. Как элементы попали туда? - например были добавлены с помощью импорта из любой другой базы.  она уже где то велась (в том же exel). Пользователь на экране тоже видит таблицу, над которой есть выпадающий список из состояний. (Ну раз пока он ничего из интерфейса не добавлял и не менял, то в выпадающем списке 1 элемент), а как только он что-то обновит, удалит (новая ревизия со статусом 0), добавит. То мы перейдем на вторую итерацию (см.вопрос) и в выпадающем списке у нас уже должна быть возможность выбрать 1 или 2.

Comment: Наверное, мне надо еще в вопросе показать, что должна на каждой итерации хранить вторая таблица. Вы процитировали мой вопрос. Но в нем на первой итерации данные выглядят иначе. Поэтому не совсем понял... А тот вид, который вы показали в ответе, будет уже, когда в базу добавится 1 элемент, и, соответственно, в интерфейсе пользователь увидит список из 2 элементов.

Comment: еще раз обновил вопрос, добавил пояснения к каждой итерации